# $httpProvider request interceptor - get parameters

Tags: angularjs

I need to add a query string to some of my $http calls.
Now $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest seems to receive 2 objects:
data and a headersGetter, neither allow me to directly change the url or add a get variable.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need an interceptor. From the angular docs on $http:

> There are two kinds of interceptors (and two kinds of rejection
>   interceptors):
>
> request: interceptors get called with http config object.
>   The function is free to modify the config or create a new one.
>   The function needs to return the config directly or as a promise.